# SCP to /opt, is it possible? (permissions)

Tags: scp

I understand that a non root user can't write to /opt.

I chowned /opt to root:wheel, and that also doesn't work even though the account that I am scp'ing with is in the wheel group.

The only thing that works is to create a subdirectory under /opt/ and chown the permissions for the scp'ing user and then scp to /opt/test which works. This however breaks the entire purpose of trying to automate deploying a bunch of large tar files to many servers at one time without manually creating the sub directories with scp account permissions.
I understand I can scp to a directory with access, and then ssh in and manually copy it to /opt, but this is not what I am after. My goal is to scp to /opt. (Not possible, correct? :-)  )

Hi Folks, Updating per request:
  ON a default CentOS install /opt is root:root.
The user in question is in visudo as ALL=(ALL) ALL under 'roots' entry, and not a member of wheel.  I did find a work around. I precreated a directory under /opt that is set to this users account and group (i.e. /opt/newdir),  scp'ing to a tmp dir, untarring there and copying directory and files to /opt/newdir which worked perfectly.

Thanks everyone for your responses.

Comment: The group doesn't have write permissions to `/opt`, at least on my system (`ls -ld /opt` => `drwxr-xr-x`). Nor should it have, ever, imho.

Comment: there is nothing special about /opt.  if the permissions allow a user or group member to write to it, then they can. if not, then they can't.  same as any other directory.   note that allowing users to write to or own files/dirs in /opt is, as a general rule, a bad idea.

Comment: Bruce, please would you add `ls -ld /opt` to your question. Also, output of `id | grep wheel >/dev/null && echo wheel` using the target account.

Comment: @roaima `wheel` is group 0 (aka `root`). On *bsd, you put a user in group 0 in order to be able to use `su(1)`, not to write files inside `/opt`, `/usr` or `/etc`. The group 0 having write perms _anywhere_ would be quite unexpected on any system.

Comment: @mosvy yep. But this OP has set `root:wheel` on `/opt`, so I want to ascertain that the configuration's valid.